# laravel - trying to remove item from fetched collection

Tags: php, laravel

I need to remove items from a collection based on an attribute (Laravel 5.6).

```
$leagues = League::all();

foreach($leagues as $i => $L){
  if($L->status == LeagueStatus::HIDDEN){

    $leagues->forget($i); <<<<======== 1st attempt
    unset($leagues[$i]);  <<<<======== 2nd attempt

  }
}

return response()->json($leagues->toArray());
```

Both methods removes the items correctly, but causes that response JSON comes as object:

```
{         <<<<======== ITS OBJECT WITH NUMBERED KEYS, NOT ARRAY
  "0":{
    "id":1,
    "title":"test...
```

Correct JSON would be:

```
[         <<<<======== NORMAL ARRAY WITH OBJECTS
  {
    "id":1,
    "title":"test...
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `values` to get a new Collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers:

```
return response()->json($leagues->values());
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `values`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-values)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this

```
return response()->json($leagues->toArray());
```

to

```
return json_decode($leagues);
```